# MSVC project missing "__popcountdi2" when linking against GCC-built static library

Tags: c, gcc, visual-c++, mingw, static-libraries

I have a windows executable project that links against a static library (.lib) built with GCC 6 (MinGW). The following error occurs during compilation:

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __popcountdi2 referenced in function ...
```

The symbol is linked in as a result of using a GCC built-in function `__builtin_popcount()`, which resides in libgcc. However, despite adding `-static-libgcc` as an argument to gcc, the problem still persists.

Is there a way for my library (.lib) to contain parts of libgcc rather than requiring libgcc to be on the system for an executable to link against? Is some way around having to ship the library with libgcc?

`__builtin_popcount()` is not the only built-in function that I'm currently using. The library makes use of `__builtin_bswap32()`, which doesn't seem to run into this issue.

I'm using GCC 6.1.0. Updated to 6.2.0; same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that on windows, MinGW (GCC) was not detecting the current CPU architecture properly when `-march=native` was passed in. It was falling back to an architecture that did not support POPCNT as a native instruction (probably i686). As a test, `-mpopcnt` was added to the build and everything worked fine.

The fix is to manually specify the architecture using `-march=`.

**Furthermore: is this a bug with MingGW since the native architecture is not polled for properly?**